# Abelian Group proof 1

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups

Recall that a $\Bbb Z$-module is an abelian group ($G$,$+$) together with a map $\Bbb Z$ $\times$ $G$ $\to$ $G$ $:$ $(a, x)$ $\mapsto$ $ax$ (Scalar multiplication) such that

(a) $a(x+y) = ax + ay$  for all $a$ $\in$ $\Bbb Z$, $x,y\in G$

(b) $(a+b)x$ = $ax + bx$ for all $a,b \in \Bbb Z$, $x\in G$

(c) $(ab)x$ = $a(bx)$ for all $a,b \in \Bbb Z$, $x\in G$

(d) $1x$ = $x$ for all $x \in G$

Let ($G$, $+$) be an abelian group. Prove that there is *at most one* scalar multiplication $\Bbb Z$ $\times$ $G$ $\to$ $G$ $:$ $(a, x)$ $\mapsto$ $ax$ making it into a $\Bbb Z$-module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from the axioms that
$$(1+1+\cdots+1)x=x+x+\cdots+x$$
This uniquely determines the action of each positive integer. For zero we have
$$(0+0)x=0x+0x=0x$$
So
$$0x=0x-0x=0$$
This tells us the action for negative integers; we have
$$0=(a+-a)x=ax+(-a)x$$
Thus
$$(-a)x=-(ax)$$
That is, $(-a)x$ is the inverse of $ax$.